# MVC 3: AutoMapper and Project/Solution Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, projects-and-solutions

I've just started to use AutoMapper in my MVC 3 project and I'm wondering how people here structure their projects when using it.  I've created a `MapManager` which simply has a `SetupMaps` method that I call in global.asax to create the initial map configurations.  I also need to use a `ValueResolver` for one of my mappings.  For me, this particular `ValueResolver` will be needed in a couple of different places and will simply return a value from `Article.GenerateSlug`.

So my questions are:

1. How do you manage the initial creation of all of your maps (`Mapper.CreateMap`)?
2. Where do you put the classes for your `ValueResolver`s in your project?  Do you create subfolders under your Model folder or something else entirely?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i won't speak to question 2 as its really personal preference, but for 1 i generally use one or more `AutoMapper.Profile` to hold all my `Mapper.CreateMap` for a specific purpose (domaintoviewmodel, etc).

```
public class ViewModelToDomainAutomapperProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get
        {
            return "ViewModelToDomain";
        }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<TripRegistrationViewModel, TripRegistration>()
            .ForMember(x=>x.PingAttempts, y => y.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x=>x.PingResponses, y => y.Ignore());
    }
}
```

then i create a bootstrapper (`IInitializer`)  that configures the Mapper, adding all of my profiles.

```
public class AutoMapperInitializer : IInitializer
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
                            {
                                x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelAutomapperProfile>();
                                x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainAutomapperProfile>();
                            });
    }
}
```

then in my global.asax i get all instances of `IInitializer` and loop through them running `Execute()`.

```
foreach (var initializer in ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IInitializer>())
            {
                initializer.Execute();
            }
```

that's my general strategy.

---

by request, here is the reflection implementation of the final step.

```
var iInitializer = typeof(IInitializer);

List<IInitializer> initializers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => iInitializer.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass)
    .Select(x => (IInitializer) Activator.CreateInstance(x)).ToList();

foreach (var initializer in initializers)
{
    initializer.Execute();
}
```

Comment: I like the look of this.  I do have one question though.  I don't know what `ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances` is.  From Googling, it seems to be a part of StructureMap.  I've never used that so is there a .NET BCL equivalent of `ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances`?  Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: if you're not using an ioc container, start. structuremap is what i use mostly, but there are others.  i've updated my answer with the .net reflection way of doing things.  its pretty simple.

Comment: @johnh, no problem. be sure to use the IInitializer stuff for more than just automapper. think anything that you would normally put in the global.asax. otherwise the cost of reflection isn't really worth it.

Comment: Will do.  I appreciate this sort of comment because I've still only been using MVC for a few weeks.